# Remove bad node from ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

We feel there is a bad node is our cluster. First, there were 2 shards which were not able to initialize, digging deeper we found both are trying to connect to a node. We found that node to be very old EC2 machine and have weird name (prefixed with domU-).
We decided to shut down ES on the node. We see that the node was shutdown gracefully. And there are 9 nodes in cluster (1 less than the original count.)

However we still see several nodes trying to connect to the same bad host.
Here are the logs.

```
[2015-06-16 00:24:09,083][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [Left Hand] failed to reconnect to node [Wonder Man][r9EW8A7ySOmrFl5y-Mflfg][domU-12-31-39-05-39-61][inet[/10.241.58.143:9300]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Wonder Man][inet[/10.241.58.143:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:727)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:656)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:624)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:146)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$ReconnectToNodes.run(InternalClusterService.java:518)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Comment: Is it possible that your 9 other nodes are using [unicast discovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#unicast) and have an explicit list of hosts configured in their `elasticsearch.yml` file? You need to look for the settings named `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`and check if your old node is in that list.

Comment: Checked unicast etc, but still We could not find the root cause, there must be some stale cache. Finally stopped and restarted all the nodes all at once, that solved the issue.